# A word that encapsulates either "vacation" and "holiday"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms, generic-term

I am looking for a word that would generalize the "vacation" and "holiday" concepts. So a phrase that would represent the time taken away from work/business without specifying whether this time off is due to holiday or vacation. The phrase need only represent time taken away due to vacation and holiday, other absences like medical or familial are not necessary, but if the phrase is general enough to include these that is fine.

I am leaning towards "leave of absence", but I am not convinced this is the best choice.

Comment: In the UK at least, 'holiday' covers both _leave_ and _vacation_. // Closely related: [Is there a difference between 'holiday' and 'vacation'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31166/is-there-a-difference-between-holiday-and-vacation)

Comment: You are taking some [**leave²**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/leave). You will be away from work, and the reason isn't stated or implied.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/vacation

Comment: In the US, a hypernym is PTO or Personal Time Off. However this might include taking time off for getting your car fixed too.